# App in phone is blank when debug, ANDROID STUDIO - REACT NATIVE

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I want to run the app in my phone, im running the emulator and my phone, the problem is that it says that everything is fine but doesnt show the app, in the emulator is working fine, why is this happenig?

the emulator:

[image]

real phone:

[image]

why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Expo is stuck on your Android phone. I'd try the common tricks - reboot phone, kill expo process and reload it, and lastly republish the App on Expo.

Comment: Rebbot phone? It's the first time that I do this and already have to reboot?

Comment: Yes, in my experience at least on Android it glitches far more often than on iPhone

Comment: im using expo now, but theres another problem with the component ```react-native-share``` can you go there and help me?